# Inc/dec logic to traverse multiple array values and store position in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object that contains 2 arrays `up` and `down`, these values should be linked to up and down keys, ticking up you should move through the `up` array, if you tick down you should through any `up` tick values (if `up` ticks have happened) through to the `down` array and vice-versa.

I've managed to create a version of this but having some issues getting `undefined` at what I would deem to be the cross-over point between up and down. Could someone possibly provide me with some advice on how to make this more robust and solve the `undefined` issue? Should I start at -1 for my counter or what should the approach be?

**JS**

```
var prices = {
    "up" : [
      {"r": 10.25, "f" : "10.25"},
      {"r": 10.50, "f" : "10.50"},
      {"r": 10.75, "f" : "10.75"},
      {"r": 11.00, "f" : "11.00"},
      {"r": 11.25, "f" : "11.25"},
      {"r": 11.50, "f" : "11.50"},
      {"r": 11.75, "f" : "11.75"},
      {"r": 12.00, "f" : "12.00"},
      {"r": 12.25, "f" : "12.25"},
      {"r": 12.50, "f" : "12.50"}
    ],
    "down": [
        {"r": 7.50, "f" : "7.50"},
        {"r": 7.75, "f" : "7.75"},
        {"r": 8.00, "f" : "8.00"},
        {"r": 8.25, "f" : "8.25"},
        {"r": 8.50, "f" : "8.50"},
        {"r": 8.75, "f" : "8.75"},
        {"r": 9.00, "f" : "9.00"},
        {"r": 9.25, "f" : "9.25"},
        {"r": 9.50, "f" : "9.50"},
        {"r": 9.75, "f" : "9.75"} 
    ]
};

var $btns = $('.js-btn');
var counter = -1;

$btns.on('click', function(event) {
    var dir = $(event.currentTarget).data('dir');

    if(dir === 'up') {
        if(counter >= -1) {
            console.log(prices[dir][++counter]);
        } else {
            console.log(prices['down'][prices['down'].length + counter++]);
        }   
    }

    if(dir === 'down') {
        if(counter <= -1) {
            console.log(prices[dir][prices[dir].length + counter--]);
        } else {
            console.log(prices['up'][--counter]);
        }

    }
});
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/7Lznj00w/

Comment: Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/7Lznj00w/18/

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that your array accesses are valid, you want the array index to be in the range `[0, arr.length-1]`. If you attempt to access a JavaScript array at an invalid index, you'll get undefined.

You can initialize your `upIndex` and `downIndex` to `0` (the first element in the list). Now suppose you want the next element in the up array. You can update upIndex as follows

```
upIndex = (upIndex + 1) % prices.up.length
```

The `%` operator gives you the remainder after division (so `3 % 2` is `1` since `3/2` leaves a remainder of `1`). So if you are already at the last index in `up` it will start you over at the beginning. The last index in up is 9, and up.length is 10, so `upIndex = (9 + 1) % 10 = 0`, ensuring that you always stay within the bounds of the array.

Comment: Hey, the plan is to request more prices when I get to the upper regions of both the up and down arrays, I'm more concerned about nailing down the logic to traverse up and down the correct arrays based on the previous action - so if i tick up twice then tick down i move down the up array etc

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.clear();

var prices = {
    "up" : [
      {"r": 10.25, "f" : "10.25"},
      {"r": 10.50, "f" : "10.50"},
      {"r": 10.75, "f" : "10.75"},
      {"r": 11.00, "f" : "11.00"},
      {"r": 11.25, "f" : "11.25"},
      {"r": 11.50, "f" : "11.50"},
      {"r": 11.75, "f" : "11.75"},
      {"r": 12.00, "f" : "12.00"},
      {"r": 12.25, "f" : "12.25"},
      {"r": 12.50, "f" : "12.50"}
    ],
    "down": [
     {"r": 7.50, "f" : "7.50"},
        {"r": 7.75, "f" : "7.75"},
        {"r": 8.00, "f" : "8.00"},
        {"r": 8.25, "f" : "8.25"},
        {"r": 8.50, "f" : "8.50"},
        {"r": 8.75, "f" : "8.75"},
        {"r": 9.00, "f" : "9.00"},
        {"r": 9.25, "f" : "9.25"},
        {"r": 9.50, "f" : "9.50"},
        {"r": 9.75, "f" : "9.75"} 
    ]
};

var $btns = $('.js-btn');
var counter = -1;

$btns.on('click', function(event) {
    var dir = $(event.currentTarget).data('dir');
    
    if(dir === 'up') {
/*use return; to stop or reset counter = -1 | 0*/
if(!prices[dir][counter+1])return;
         counter++;
        if(counter >= -1) {
            console.log(prices[dir][counter]);
        } else {
         console.log(prices['down'][prices['down'].length + counter]);
        }   
    }
    
    if(dir === 'down') {
/*use return; to stop or reset counter = -1 | 0*/
if(!prices[dir][counter-1])return;
        counter--;
        if(counter <= -1) {
            console.log(prices[dir][prices[dir].length + counter]);
        } else {
            console.log(prices['up'][counter]);
        }
        
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block  js-btn" data-dir="up">Up</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block  js-btn" data-dir="down">Down</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this is close but if I go down through all the down values then back up I will still get an undefined happening after value 9.5? {
  "r": 9.5,
  "f": "9.50"
}
undefined

Comment: Hey! The updated version doesn't seem to go down through the down values now :/

Comment: Yes, the updated code prevent to set counter to be negative.
Do you want to reset counter if the maximun/minimum reached?

Comment: So you're first attempt was so close bar that 1 undefined that was happening at some point, thats the approach I'm after - click up button move up 1 in up array, click down array move down 1 in up array, click down again move into down array

Comment: Will you have any problem to copy your json to new array sorted then use counter to go up and down?

Comment: I'm afraid it needs to be split out to 2 arrays as I need to request additional up/down prices etc